# How to change sender name in ssmtp?

Tags: email, smtp, ssmtp

I have installed ssmtp on my Linux server. Apache server works under www-data user, and send mail from ssmtp. In recieved emails I see www-data in sender name. How can I change it?

Here`s my configs:

/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

```
mailhub=smtp.gmx.com:587
hostname=mysite.com
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=username@gmx.us
AuthPass=password
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

/etc/ssmtp/revaliases

```
root:username@gmx.us
user:username@gmx.us
www-data:username@gmx.us
```

Answer (score 12):

You could change the user finger information for user 'www-data', namelly the 'Full Name" finger parameter.

You may do so using Linux **'chfn'** command:

```
chfn -f "Email Sender Name" www-data
```

What this does is setting/changing the *real name* for that user in the finger information (stored in the */etc/passwd* file -cf [chfn man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chfn.1.html)-).

Alternatively you could use the Linux **'usermod'** command as follow (though Linux manual states this is normally modified using the chfn utility - cf [user mod man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/usermod.8.html) - ):

```
usermod -c "Email Sender Name" www-data
```

This worked for me.